# How do I read two CSV files and compare 1 column from both and then write to a new file where columns match

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 CSV's with some names in them. There are few duplicates in each CSV, I need to compare them and if the same names exist in both CSV, update in new CSV.

CSV 1

```
ID, Names
    1, Bill
    2, Smith
```

CSV 2

```
ID, Names
    1, James
    2, Gates
    3, Bill
```

As first row in CSV 1 matches with 3rd row in CSV 2

New CSV [Desired Output]

```
ID, Names
    1, Bill
```

I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')

df1['flag'] = 'old'
df2['flag'] = 'new'

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

dups = df.drop_duplicates(df.columns.difference(['flag']), keep = False)
dups.to_csv('new_CSV.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: The first row in csv1 does not match the third row in csv2. The names do but the IDs are different.

Comment: Yes, I'm only comparing names.

Comment: maybe you want to use merge like: `df1.merge(df2, on='Names')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2[['Names']],how='inner',on='Names')
Out[44]: 
   ID  Names
0   1   Bill
```